# Gstreamer plugin get video meta data, library not linked?

Tags: video, gstreamer, meta, dynamic-linking

When I call these functions:

```
meta_api = gst_video_meta_api_get_type();
crop_meta = gst_buffer_get_video_crop_meta (buffer);
meta = gst_buffer_get_video_meta (buffer);
```

Obviously, I need to include these header files:

```
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <gst/video/video.h>
#include <gst/video/gstvideometa.h>
```

The gstreamer library is dynamically linked at runtime. When I run the whole pipeline through gst-launch-1.0. I got this error:

```
undefined symbol: gst_video_meta_api_get_type
```

And all the function call about gstmeta would not work.
I have struggled on this for a long time. Please help!

My gstreamer is installed through compiling source code.
Any other function call are fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you linking against `-lgstvideo-1.0 -lgstbase-1.0` ?

Comment: Thank you! I add the link library thing in the makefile, and it just worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure you are linking against the needed libraries.

For the base plugins link against `-lgstbase-1.0` and for video plugins link against `-lgstvideo-1.0`. I am not 100% sure which of the two that function resides but linking against both will fix it for you.